# scan landscape page

Tags: scanner

I visited hoping to find a procedure to scan some pages in landscape orientation.  I found some handy tips but not landscape.

I found a solution using XSane (below).  There can always be other solutions, there usually are on a Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

After scanning a page, XSane usually presents an A4 page in portrait mode.  You can change this:

1. Select the scanned image you want in landscape orientation
2. Press the `[Edit image]` button
3. On the tool bar there are buttons to rotate the image.
4. Choose the rotation that suits your page orientation
5. Review the result
6. Save the image
7. Press `[Save multipage file]` to generate a PDF or other file output.

The result will have the rotated pages appearing as landscape.